# Clearing RAM after disposing of windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, ram, using

I wrote a test program to find out how to clear memory after closing a windows form in C#. I have read up on the problem, and I have tried everything that was suggested (so please don't mark this as a duplicate question).

One of the suggestions was using the `using` statement, some people recommended the `Dispose()` method, so I'm using both at the same time.

In my test project I created a Form, I placed a PictureBox in it containing a huge picture (to use more RAM) and nothing else. The code in my Program.cs is as follows:

```
using (Form1 form = new Form1())
{
   Application.Run(form);
   form.Dispose();
}
```

One suggestion was forcing the Garbage Collector to run, so I even added

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Yet I'm watching the Diagnostic tools inside Visual Studio and it says Process Memory is still 122MB.

EDIT: From comments it became clear to me that disposing of a Form doesn't dispose of everything in it. I guess my question is, whether there's a clean way to do it, or do I need to loop through everything and make sure everything I've ever referenced is disposed?

EDIT: For futher clarification, I changed the Program.cs to the following, and added a random not null string to my form's class, and removed everything else. As soon as the form is loaded it closes.

```
  while (true)
  {
      using (Form1 f = new Form1())
      {
           Application.Run(f);
      }
      GC.Collect();
      GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  }
```

As the program runs through this infinite loop, the VS diagnostic tools window shows how the memory usage slowly but surely climb up.

Comment: `using` calls `Dispose()` automatically, doing it manually defeats the purpose of `using`

Comment: Dispose the image on the picturebox and do a `GC.Collect()`

Comment: So if I have a complicated form, I have to go through every control containing anything and dispose of them?

Comment: That depends on how you are loading the image, so please add that code

Comment: It's added using the Visual Studio designer generated code (this.pictureBox1.Image = global::test.Properties.Resources.picturename) But the project I need this for has hundreds of controls and many pictures

Comment: Your program runs for a fraction of a millisecond with less memory before it terminates.  The odds that you can see that tiny blip are very low.  Micro-benchmarks are very rarely useful to expose problems in a real app.  Use a good memory profiler (good == not free) and focus on the pictures, they don't get disposed automatically.

Comment: I'd think that the image is not being unloaded then, as it might still be referenced

Comment: Each call to resources creates a new image.  SInce you create it, you need to dispose of it.  If you are showing different images for different things, dispose of the old one before creating a new one

Comment: No, you do not need to loop thru everything - just the things that you create which ought be disposed.  We have no context for what the app does (or how), so broad generalities are all you are likely to get...and when more than one person has commented on a post, you need to use @+username as in @TamásTörök for them to get pinged since this is not a discussion group

Comment: @Plutonix You are right, sorry :)  Basically my question is why does the current memory usage of my application increase every time I create and remove a form that has ANYTHING in it. For example a random string. Why doesn't the Garbage Collector take care of it when the whole form is disposed?

Comment: Thats a different question but there is still no context (and not sure how a form has a string "on" it).  It could be how you are creating them/it; it could be something you are doing in the form; and it could be how you are measuring the alleged leak.  GC is not instantaneous, it cleans up when it needs to.

Comment: @Plutonix It's the same context, the form was created like the example above. I removed the picturebox, so the form is completely empty, and in the form's class i declared a string and gave it a random value. The form is not doing anything, and i'm using visual studio's Diagnostic tools to measure it. Also i'm even forcing GC to clean up, and waiting for a while.

Comment: We *never* had any context for what you are doing or how.  In the code shown, the app will terminate a few microseconds after you close the form, so I have no idea how you are pausing, waiting and measuring.   use a button to create one or many forms and another to dispose of them to see when GC kicks in.

Comment: @Plutonix I edited the question again, hopefully giving you enough information. Please forgive me for being such a noob, i appreciate you trying to help me greatly! :)

Comment: That is an insane test.  Create a more realistic one, like from a button click and disposing of the thing in another.  But Forms take care of themselves and all the things added via the designer (on GC's timetable - not yours)